# Android app made in html/js- hitting external url

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova

I have created an android app (html/css/js --> phonegap -->android studio --> myapp.apk).

The app calls an external url (ex:www.abcd.com/ujoimmk/inkl) which returns a json, I then use the resultant json in my app.

The problem is nothing happens when I make the call and I am unable to debug the issue.

```
$.getJSON('https://www.abcd.com/ujoimmk/inkl', function(data) {});
```

When I check the same in web browser I face X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN access error, how do we solve it in app?

Comment: run it  on a phone and debug it with chrome inspect. 
what does it mean nothing happens? you see the request in the network section in the developer tool?

Comment: i ran it using android studio emulator and i got the following error "W/SystemWebViewClient: URL blocked by whitelist: https://www.abcd.com/ujoimmk/inkl" Any info on how to fix this ?

Comment: cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git

Answer (score 0):

Actually X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN was never an issue with the emulator, it was a minor syntax error which was blocking me, solving which fixed my impasse.